# App disappears from Win7's ALT-TAB list sometimes

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2010, alt-tab

I've been having some trouble with one of my Delphi 2010 projects lately.  It seems that sometimes, when I have a form open as a modal dialog, the app stops showing up in the ALT-TAB list until I close the dialog.  It's still in the Taskbar, but not in ALT-TAB, which means I can't switch to it without using the mouse.

Running under Windows 7, 64-bit.  Has anyone seen this before?  Any idea what causes it and how to fix it?

Comment: It's probably not much help to you, but I see this from time to time with various apps on 64-bit Vista.  I haven't realized if there is a pattern, but I haven't been watching that closely for one.

Comment: Does your project .dpr contain the "Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := True;" line?

Comment: @Warren: It does.  Is that part of the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It's a Feature of Windows 7, and not a bug.

The solution is to either remove the 'Tool window' from the Dialog Properties, or to remove 'WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW' from the RC file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore the expected Win XP behavior, just add a DWORD registry key named

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AltTabSettings

And set the value to 1

You’re welcome :)

Comment: Don't use a global state to manage a local problem.[1] The end-user doesn't necessarily want all of their windows to suddenly act differently in alt+tab. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx (I know this post is old but I stumbled across it and I assume someone else could too)